# View not updated after modifying the array data in angular 6

Tags: javascript, angular

I am deleting data from array and trying to update the view but it is not working.

```
  async deleteProduct(e) {
    try {
      const data = await this.rest.get(environment.apiUrl + `/api/seller/products/delete/?id=${e.target.id}`);
      data['success'] ? this.products = (this.products.filter(e => e != (data['products'].id))) : this.data.error(data['message']);
    } catch (error) {
      this.data.error(error['message']);
    }
  }
```

Html:

```
<section id="myProducts">
  <div class="container p-5">
    <app-message></app-message>
    <div *ngIf="!products" class="m-auto">
      <h1 class="text-center display-3 mt-5">
        <i class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin"></i>
      </h1>
    </div>
    <h3 *ngIf="products && !products.length" class="display-2 text-center mt-5">My Products is Empty</h3>
    <div *ngIf="products && products.length" class="row">
      <div class="col">
        <h4 class="display-4">My Products</h4>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="offset-10 col-2 d-none d-md-block">
            <p>
              <small class="text-muted">Price</small>
            </p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <hr class="mt-0">
        <div *ngFor="let product of products" class="product">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-4 col-md-2">
              <a routerLink="/product/{{ product.id }}">
                <img src="{{ product.image }}" alt="image" class="img-fluid img-thumbnail">
              </a>
            </div>
            <div class="col-5 col-md-8">
              <h5>
                <a routerLink="/product/{{ product.id }}">{{ product.title }}</a>
                <p class="m-0">
                  <small class="text-muted">{{ product.category.name }}</small>
                </p>
              </h5>
            </div>
            <div class="col-2">
              <h6 class="font-weight-bold text-danger" >{{ product.price | currency : 'INR' }}</h6>
            </div>
            <div class="col-2">
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-info" id="{{product.id}}" (click)="editProduct($event)" [disabled]="btnDisabled">Edit</button>
            </div>
            <div class="col-2">
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-info" id="{{product.id}}" (click)="deleteProduct($event)" [disabled]="btnDisabled">Delete</button>
            </div>
          </div>
          <hr>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

After deleting the item from array, I am trying to update the object like this:

```
this.products = (this.products.filter(e => e != (data['products'].id)))
```

Comment: Did you set the `changeDetection` to `ChangeDetectionStrategy.onPush`?

Comment: @Batajus I am not sure how to do that? I am new to angular 6

Comment: No you don't need to do that. It's just a question. Does the updating of your products array works correctly?

Comment: @Batajus I didnt set any change detection

Answer (score 0):

It seems so that your view does not check the changes of your `products` array.

So I would say trigger it manually:

Inject[ChangeDetectorRef](https://angular.io/api/core/ChangeDetectorRef) to trigger change detection manually.

```
constructor(private cd: ChangeDetectorRef){....}
```

And in your method call `this.cd.detectChanges()`:

```
async deleteProduct(e) {
    ...
    data['success'] ? this.products = (this.products.filter(e => e != (data['products'].id))) : this.data.error(data['message']);
    this.cd.detectChanges();
    ...
}
```

Comment: Do you really receive `data['products'].id` from your server call?

Comment: I fixed it. The issue was in array.filter. I had to use the `e._id` in `data['success'] ? this.products = (this.products.filter(e => e._id != (data['products'].id))) : this.data.error(data['message']);`

Answer (score 0):

you are comparing e to != e['products'].id ..
it is not true.
i think you should be checking the variable which holds the id in your "e"

which means

e.id != ...or something like so.

I Hope it is working.